# CALayer -displayLayer:inContext: never called during frame/bounds animation

Tags: uikit, core-animation, calayer

I need to animate the frame of a CALayer instance; during the animation I should also update/redraw the content of the layer based upon the new size (frame by frame) of it.

I've tried to watch and use -displayLayer:inContext: of CALayer (it's a delegate property) but It does not work: both with frame (it's a derived property of bounds/location/anchorPoint) and bounds animation I can't receive this message (it should be called by CALayer's internal drawInContext: method) during the animation process.

Using needsDisplayOnBoundsChange I can get it called at the end of the animation, but nothing with bounds.
It works fine with custom properties (I need to return YES on needsDisplayForKey method).

Any idea?
Is possible to force redraw of CALayer contents during bounds/frame animation?